# How to maintain two tables data in single view page using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[![enter image description here][1]][1][enter image description here][2]I have two tables invoice and invoice_description, The column `invoice_no` is common for both tables, I want to fetch the data from `invoice` table name,address,invoice_no and next table `invoice_description` I want to fetch product description, quantity, price and more.
this is my table structure

```
                        invoice
         --------------------------------------
          name   bill_no   invoice_no   address    price
           adi     1        2           adasdasd     12
           abc     2        3           adasdas       13


                       invoice_description
        -----------------------------------------------------
               product   invoice_no  quantity 
                a          2          1
                b          2          2
                c          3          3

     i wana output like when i pass invoice_no 2
               invoice_no:-2     name- adi
                product          quantity
                 a                 1
                 b                 2
```

**This is my controller:-**

```
public function invoice($id)
{
            //echo $id;
        $this->load->database();  
             //load the model  
        $this->load->model('useradmin');  
            //$invoice=$this->useradmin->selectdealer($id);  
            //$invoicedes=$this->useradmin->selectdealer1($id);  
            //$data['invoice']=$invoice;
            //$data['invoicedes']=$invoicedes;
            //$this->load->view('envoice',$data);  
          //
        $query = $this->useradmin->selectdealer($id);
        $ids = $this->useradmin->selectdealer1($id);  
        $data['dealers'] =  $query;
        $data['id'] = $ids;                     
        $this->load->view('envoice',$data);
    }

}
```

**My model is:-**

```
public function selectdealer($id)  
{  
    //data is retrive from this query  
    //echo $id;           
    //$this->db->select('*');  
    //$this->db-from('invoice_description');
    $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('invoice_description');
    return $query->result();
}   
public function selectdealer1($id)  
{  
    //data is retrive from this query  
    //echo $id;
    $query = $this->db->get('invoice');  
    $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
    return $query->result();    
}
```

I want invoice no, name, and address from `invoice` table 
    and more than one product description from `invoice_description` table

I m trying my view page is

invoice_no :-123
name:-xyzx

product des   price  quantity
asdaf          12     10
asafsa          12    13

Comment: select all code and press ctrl k so it indent properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller

```
public function invoice($id)
{
    $this->load->database();  
    $this->load->model('useradmin');  
    $data['dealer'] = $this->useradmin->selectdealer($id);
    $this->load->view('envoice',$data);
}
```

In model

```
public function selectdealer($id)  
{  
    $this->db->select("name, address, invoice_no");
    $this->db->from('invoice');
    $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get()->row_array();
    return $result;
}
```

In view

```
foreach($dealer as $row){
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['address'];

        $query = $this->db->get_where('invoice_description', array('invoice_no' => $row['invoice_no']));
$results = $query->result_array();
print_r($results);
    foreach($results as $desc){
        echo $desc['quantity'];
        echo $desc['price'];
        echo $desc['desc'];
    } 
}
```

Comment: print_r($invoice_data); it returns all the data from row i wana only one row who matched in id

Comment: it returns all the data from table

Comment: $data['invoice_description_data']= $this->useradmin->selectdealer($id);
$data['invoice_data'] = $this->useradmin->selectdealer1($id);

Comment: $data['invoice_data']=returns all the data

Comment: $q = $this->db->get();
        $result = $q->row_array();

Comment: I think your table names are wrong otherwise it will working code.

Comment: Please check at once that column name and table name is right or not and identical relate to each other

Comment: if table name is wrong than how its return all the data from table

Comment: i post all the details in new question

Comment: i post new question pls saw it

Comment: echo $row['invoice_no']; illegal string offstring invoice_no

Comment: dekho adi select me sab table column sahi hai ya nhi kyuki tumne table structure provide nhi kiya ho sakta hai spell mistake ho mujhse. Or usi k according view me $dealer ko print kar k dekho

Comment: maine ek aur question dala jisme puri detail hai dekh lo bhai

Comment: tum sirf table structure ka screenshot daal do uska data nhi dikhega. Isse confusion nhi hoga ek baar me sahi result milega

Comment: how to attach screenshot

Comment: CLICK ON THIS https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2704821/a3ca9e650ff3e5b953dcb772d57e72cf

Comment: Illegal string offset 'name'

Comment: change in model 'row_array' to  'result_array()'

Comment: $query = $this->db->get_where('invoice_description', array('invoice_no' => $row['invoice_no']))->result_array();
    print_r($query);  this line is error occured

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: there is small mistake for my site thnks for helping me bro can u join me with fb

Comment: your answer? me samjha nhi kon se answer ka bol rhe

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
//Assign empty array $data and assign a results to the respective array
$data['invoice_description_data']= $this->useradmin->selectdealer($id);
$data['invoice_data'] = $this->useradmin->selectdealer1($id); 
$this->load->view('envoice',$data);
```

In View

```
//call 
print_r($invoice_data);
print_r($invoice_description_data);
```

Comment: print_r($invoice_data);

Comment: return all the row in our table i wana only one row matched in id

Comment: @AdiSingh in model use join and return results single row then print it

Comment: $data['dealers'] =  $query;
        $data['id'] = $ids;  only one $data can work properly $data['id'] returns all the value on table i would only one i pass $id but its not work properly

Comment: send some demo suneelkumar

Comment: @AdiSingh how is your database structure and rows put some samples in your question. Is id's are duplicate check it once.

Comment: $query = $this->useradmin->selectdealer($id);
        $ids = $this->useradmin->selectdealer1($id);  
        $data['dealers'] =  $query;
        $data['id'] = $ids;                     
        $this->load->view('envoice',$data);   $data['id'] returns all row in the table

Comment: foreach($id as $ids){ echo $ids->invoice_no;} it returns all data in the table

Comment: @AdiSingh it's not correct results, check which id what u parse and also check query. `$this->db->select('*');  
    $this->db-from('invoice');
    $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);`

Comment: You need only one record right? check your query and change it.

Comment: Try this `$query = $this->db-query(select * from invoice where invoice_no='$id'); return $query->row_array();`

Comment: is your table name `invoice` ? and column name `invoice_no`?

Comment: i post new question with all details pls saw it

Answer (score 0):

```
public function selectdealer($invoice_id) {
    $this->db->select('invoice.*, invoice_description.*')
                 ->from('invoice')
                 ->join('invoice_description', 'invoice.invoice_no = invoice_description.invoice_no');
    ->where ( "invoice.invoice_no='".$invoice_id."' ",'',FALSE );
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

use join to retrieve data from two table

```
foreach($row as $invoicedata){   
    display your data here
}
```

Comment: what about view

Comment: foreach($row as $invoicedata){

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function selectdealer($id)  
  {           
     if(!empty($id))
     {
     $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
     $query = $this->db->get('invoice');
     return $query->result();     
     }
  }
```

this work for invoice name correctly 
but error on this line

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('invoice_description', array('invoice_no' => $row['invoice_no']))->result_array();
print_r($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function selectdealer($id)  
    {  
     if(!empty($id))
         {
    $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('invoice');
    return $query->result();  
         }
    }   
   public function selectdealer1($id)  
     {  

     if(!empty($id))
        {
            $this->db->where('invoice_no', $id);
         $query = $this->db->get('invoice_description');  
        return $query->result();  
     }  
  }
```

those function works for me correctly thanku friends aap logo ko mare help karne kaye liye